# Number of divisors of $9!$ which are of the form $3m+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Total number  of divisors of $9!$ which are is in the form of $3m+2$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$

My Try: Let  $ N = 9! = 1\times 2 \times 3 \times 2^2 \times 5 \times 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 2^3 \times 3^2 = 2^7 \times 3^4 \times 5 \times 7$

Now If Here $N$ must be a mutiple of $3m+2$, means when $N$ is divided by $3$ It will gave a remainder $2$

But I did not understand how can i proceed further, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If the factor is of the form $3m+2$, then the prime factorization must be of the form

$$ 2^a \times 3^0 \times 5^b \times 7^c, $$

where $a+b \equiv 1 \pmod{2} $ and $ c= 0$ or $1$.

Count the number of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

There are $8 \times 2 \times 2=32$ divisors of $2^7 \times 5 \times 7$, and each is congruent to either $1 \pmod 3$ or $2 \pmod 3$.

If $2^i$ exactly divides the divisor $d$, for $i \in \{0,2,4,6\}$, we pair it up with the divisor $2d$.  Each pair consists of one divisor congruent to $1 \pmod 3$ and one congruent to $2 \pmod 3$.

So exactly $16$ of the divisors of $2^7 \times 5 \times 7$ are of the form $2 \pmod 3$.  These are the only divisors of $9!$ congruent to $2 \pmod 3$.